# Is there any quick way to do without doing manually in excel

Tags: excel

I am having column group 1 with 3 records and two more columns.For example

```
Group       level1   level2
141           a         d
256           x         t
```

what I want to achieve is the following

```
Group  level
141      a
141      d
256      x
256      t
```

the level varies depends on the group but not less than 2 and greater than 7.please help me

Comment: on levels, will proceeding levels have something in or can they be blank?

Comment: This is called "unpivot". And the answer is: no, there is no *quick* way to do that *manually*.

Comment: @iDevlop if the answer is no it cant be done, then how do you explain the results in my answer?

Comment: @ForwardEd read my comment: I never said it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use a helper column to count the number of entries per group number.  I am also assuming that each group number is unique.  The data is assumed to be layed out as per the image below

[image: Data Layout]

In column I starting in I2 and copying down to the bottom of the table use the following formula to keep a running total of the number of level entries.

```
=COUNTA(B$2:H2)
```

To generate your column of Group IDs use the following in K2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A1)-1,$I$2:$I$5,1),0)+1),"all group numbers have been listed")
```

To generate the corresponding level entries, use the following in L2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$H$5,MATCH($K2,$A$2:$A$5,0),COUNTIF($K$2:K2,K2)),"NO MORE LEVEL ENTRIES")
```

Copy L2 and K2 down as far as you need.  if you go to far you will see a prompt that there is no more information to display.  You can delete any of those rows.

[image]

Comment: the last comment in your answer says "Copy J2 and K2 down as far as you need", but above that you say to copy the forumulas to K2 and L2.  i noticed that awhile back and submitted edit to move from K2 and L2 to J2 and K2 like you wanted, but you rejected those edits so now it is still not correct.  so the alternative is just change the last paragraph to "Copy K2 and L2 down as far as you need" and then J2 is just a blank column.  its up to you, but one way or another you should fix it.