# How to transpose a column in excel relative to another?

Tags: excel, transpose

Is there a way to do transpose a column with respect to another in excel. What i am trying to do is similar to what Proc Transpose in SAS or The reshape package in R does.

```
A   1
A   2
B   1
B   2
B   4
```

I want it to transformed into this format in excel.

```
A   1   2   
B   1   2   4
```

Comment: Yes you can do this, but the first way it's listed is actually much better for Excel.  It's an ideal format for filters, formulas, pivot tables, etc.  I would highly recommend keeping the original 2-column format.

Comment: Thats true, but i want the latter for reporting some numbers. Is there a function or formula to do this?

Comment: I just answer this question [doing the opposite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314829/is-there-any-quick-way-to-do-without-doing-manually-in-excel/37315174#37315174) a couple of days ago

Comment: Will the first column always be sorted/grouped?  Also is there a maximum numbers of time "A" can occur?

Comment: yes, it will be sorted or grouped. I dont the answer to the second part. But it shouldn't be more than 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution for you is as follows.  Appologies if it is a bit convoluted, I just woke up and the fog in my head has not cleared.

In D2 place this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$1:$A$5),0,0),0)),"")
```

It will generate a unique list of items from column A

Then in column E2 use the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$D2)>=COLUMN(A:A),INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH($D2,$A$1:$A$5,0)+COLUMN(A:A)-1),"")
```

It will pull the items in column B that correspond to column A.  Copy it to the right as far as you need to go.

Both those formulas can be copied down as far as you need to go.

BONUS

Place the following in E1.  It is an array formula so instead of pressing enter when you are done with the formula, you press CTRL+SHFT+ENTER.  This is also why these formulas are also referred to as CSE formulas sometimes.

```
=MAX(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,D2:D3))&" Columns are required"
or
=MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5))&" Columns are required"
'Thanks to Scott Craner for the second formula here
```

You will know you have entered it correctly when {} appear around the formula in the formula bar.  You cannot add these {} manually.

CAVEAT

The data needs to be grouped.

Proof of concept:

[image]

Comment: Good, Mine was a good example of throwing formulas together till I get what I wanted.  Yours is more concise.

Comment: Funny you should mention that.  I think this was about the 4 or 5th iteration of how to count sideways.  I should probably add a caveat that it only works with sorted data.  And now that I am back from letting the dog out I think I will do a maximum column indicator E1.

Answer (score 3):

This formula will do what you want, I put "A" in D1 and "B" in D2.  Put this in E1 and copy over and down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,IF(COLUMN(A:A)>COUNTIF($A:$A,$D1),1500000,MATCH($D1,$A:$A,0)+COLUMN(A:A)-1)),"")
```

Make sure to copy over and down sufficient to cover all data.

[image]

Comment: What??? hard coding 15000000 (quite reasonable though) and hard coding column D as well?  Feeling ok today Scott 8) ?

Answer (score 2):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, try this short macro:

```
Sub ReOrganizer()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Na As Long, K As Long
    Dim s As String, rc As Long, Nd As Long

    rc = Rows.Count
    Range("A:A").Copy Range("D:D")
    Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Na = Cells(rc, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nd = Cells(rc, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To Nd
        s = Cells(i, "D").Value
        K = 5
        For j = 1 To Na
            If s = Cells(j, "A").Value Then
                Cells(i, K).Value = Cells(j, "B").Value
                K = K + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

***NOTE:***

- the data in column **A** is not required to be sorted.

Comment: I actually prefer the VBA approach on this one. I am running on the assumption that cells F3 are blank, where the formula methods above wind up having formulas in them displaying nothing.  The VBA code also automatically adapts to cover the correct number of columns.

Comment: @ForwardEd  Thanks...........the code is fairly simple, but if the data changes frequently,the macro would have to be re-run frequently as well.